# Do I need to escape forward slashes in a URL query string?

Tags: url

For example, is this valid and expresses `key = "ab/cd"`:

```
http://example.com?key=ab/cd
```

or do I have to percent `%` encode the `/` as in:

```
http://example.com?key=ab%2Fcd
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't think encoding is needed according to the URL RFC https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc3986#section-3.4 which says:

> ```
> query = *( pchar / "/" / "?" )
> ```
>
> characters slash ("/") and question mark ("?") may represent data
> within the query component.  Beware that some older, erroneous
> implementations may not handle such data correctly when it is used as
> the base URI for relative references (Section 5.1), apparently
> because they fail to distinguish query data from path data when
> looking for hierarchical separators.  However, as query components
> are often used to carry identifying information in the form of
> "key=value" pairs and one frequently used value is a reference to
> another URI, it is sometimes better for usability to avoid percent-
> encoding those characters.

`pchar` is defined earlier as:

```
pchar         = unreserved / pct-encoded / sub-delims / ":" / "@"
```

and `/` is not in `unreserved`, but the above quote shows that it is explicitly allowed in the query string.